# Unit Testing with jest enzyme returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, enzyme, jestjs

I'm trying to run a unit test on React. I'm using jest and enzyme.

Here's my .babelrc

```
{
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "airbnb"]
}
```

My test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { shallow, mount, render } from 'enzyme';

import Home from './Home/Home.js';

describe('Home', function() {
    it('should render without throwing an error', function() {
        expect(shallow(<Home />).contains(<div className="columns is-mobile"></div>)).toBe(true);
    });
});
```

when I run `npm test`

I get the following error:

```
FAIL  client\components\Home.test.js
  ● Test suite failed to run

    C:\Users\KeOt777\Kevin Ruiz - Front End Software Engineer\video_portal_api-master\client\components\Home\Home.css:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){.columns {
                                                                                             ^

    SyntaxError: Unexpected token .

      at ScriptTransformer._transformAndBuildScript (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/script_transformer.js:305:17)
      at Object.<anonymous> (client/components/Home/Home.js:4:1)
      at Object.<anonymous> (client/components/Home.test.js:4:13)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.373s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Can anyone help me see why my test is failing to run?

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use ES6 proxy instead. Install via npm using

```
npm install --save-dev identity-obj-proxy
```

then in your configuration file for jest, change module mapper for css to something like this

```
"\\.(css|less)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
```

See more in [jest docs](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/webpack.html#mocking-css-modules).

Comment: I will try this solution out when I get the chance, thanks in advance!